# Giant system dialog font on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, fonts, dell-xps, high-dpi

A couple of examples which should be self-explanatory -

Notepad++

[image]

Visual Studio

[image]

The setup is an XPS13 (3200 x 1800) but the screenshots are from external monitors (2 x Dell U2414H 1920 x 1080) with the laptop display disabled. I have logged out and logged back in. The issue isn't present when running the applications on the laptop screen (again, having re-logged-in) so I believe it may be related to the applications thinking they have to upscale the fonts owing to the native high dpi.

In both applications I have tried adjusting the fonts via preferences, without success.

I'm not sure if there's a hidden setting I may be missing.

Comment: have you tried right-clicking the application exe picking "properties" and then changing the "display scaling on high dpi aware" setting to "disable"?

Comment: yes, tried that for notepad++.exe : no difference. devenv.exe (for Visual Studio) doesn't have the compatibility tab, but I suspect it wouldn't make any difference. I've also tried Appearance and Personalisation > Display > Change Text Size only - they're all set to 9 point as you'd expect. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I suspect that the tabs in notepad++ are a DLL plugin, presumably so is the devenv (a shell app) and maybe the DLLs are isolated from compatability... Wild guess

Answer (score 5):

@Yorik's comment pointed me in the right direction.

The problem is, indeed, with the fonts used for [MS Shell Dlg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374112(v=vs.85).aspx) which, by default, is [Microsoft Sans Serif](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=244). The latter is described as "metrically compatible with the MS Sans bitmap font" which hints at why high-DPI scaling can get messed up.

Solution: Locate

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes
```

in the registry and change `MS Shell Dlg` to something else - `Arial` or `Tahoma` will work, but to look like the rest of Windows I chose `Segoe UI`.

Dialogs are now back to normal.